# Do two-stage compressors offer both two-stage heating *and* cooling?

Tags: hvac

I received a quote for a two-stage heat pump (model [HCH636GKA](http://icpindexing.toddsit.com/documents/086477/42831170300.pdf)). I have the following questions:

1. Does a "two-stage heat pump" imply a two-stage compressor?
2. Does a two-stage compressor guarantee two-stage heating *and* cooling? Or is it possible to end up with two-stage heating and one-stage cooling?

I can't find enough information about this particular model aside from the aforementioned spec-sheet which I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

A heat pump is an air conditioner that has valves that switch the flow of the Freon so in the winter the condensing could is the inside making heat inside and cool outside (trying to make a simple explanation).
So if the compressor is 2 stage it can run at 2 different levels, depending on brand the compressor doesn’t know if it is heating or cooling the home, except for the defrost cycle. So if it is 2 stage it should be able to do it in heating and cooling, how effective it will be depends on the air handler and if it is multi speed.

Answer (score 1):

Two-stage cooling is available with some models. A two-stage compressor probably doesn't guarantee two-stage cooling due to dependency on other components of the system.

Page 7 of the [manual](http://icpindexing.toddsit.com/documents/086477/42831170300.pdf) you linked indicates "High Cool" and "Low Cool". This would seem to imply that it does in fact offer two-stage cooling. I admit that I have not drilled into the various models to be absolutely sure. Ask your contractor or the manufacturer about your specific case.

*<sub>Disclaimer: Former home builder. Not an HVAC technician and not familiar with this model line.</sub>*

Comment: Excellent find! I agree with you, this seems to indicate the presence of 2-stage cooling. Thank you.